# vbscript to find the recent file with specific file name among all

Tags: file, vbscript

I do have only the below files.

```
New Text Document - Copy (1)

New Text Document - Copy (2)

New Text Document - Copy (3)

New Text Document - Copy (4)

New Text Document - Copy (5)
```

Apart from this I have something like

```
Test1.pdf

test2.pdf

Test3.pdf
```

My requirement is to find the latest file with file name 'New Text Document'

Comment: This might be a better question for http://superuser.com

Comment: @Mgetz No. The OP want to do that with a .wsh script or an .asp page.

Comment: @reporter Please read the list of germane topics http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am not able to copy the sample code. :( I have almost compliled it. Showing some errors///

Comment: Show your code as well as the errors, then.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started:

```
  ' need a FSO for folder access
  Dim oFS    : Set oFS    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  ' hold the file found (if any)
  Dim oFiFnd : Set oFiFnd = Nothing
  ' smallest possible number
  Dim nMax   : nMax       = 0
  ' define which files to consider
  Dim reFiNa : Set reFiNa = New RegExp
  reFiNa.Pattern = "^New Text Document - Copy \((\d+)\)$"
  Dim oFile, oMTS
  ' look at all files in folder
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder("..\testdata\17405017").Files
      Set oMTS = reFiNa.Execute(oFile.Name)
      If 1 = oMTS.Count Then
         ' file confirms to pattern
         If nMax < CLng(oMTS(0).SubMatches(0)) Then
            ' largest nMax seen so far
            nMax       = CLng(oMTS(0).SubMatches(0))
            Set oFiFnd = oFile
         End If
      End If
  Next
  If oFiFnd Is Nothing Then
     ' search failed
     WScript.Echo "No file found."
  Else
     ' success
     WScript.Echo "found", oFiFnd.Path
  End If
```

**Update wrt comment:**

If the RegExp does not find any files, then there are no files like "New Text Document - Copy (1)" in the folder. You could try @Ansgar's less strict filter - just look at the first 17 characters of the file name - or tinker with the .Pattern - e.g. ""^New Text Document - Copy ((\d+)).doc$" if you forgot the .doc extension.

Looking at @Ansgar's contribution may also help you to clarify your specs: does 'latest' mean 'last file modified' or 'highest Copy (#)'?

Comment: Many Thanks, I have modified the location and tried running . It shows no file found.  reFiNa.Pattern = "^New Text Document \((\d+)\)$"

Comment: Yes, latest means The last modified file. I have edited the regex to   reFiNa.Pattern = "^New Text Document^" Still it shows file not found ... :( Been pulling all my hairs...

Comment: @Priyabrata - the leading ^ in the .Pattern means "at the start of the string to match", so remove your trailing ^ from the pattern. For your definition of 'latest', Ansgar's approach is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate files in a folder like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\where").Files
  WScript.Echo f.Name
Next
```

Check the name of the file like this (use `LCase()` to make the check case-insensitive):

```
If LCase(Left(f.Name, 17)) = "new text document" Then
  'do stuff
End If
```

Remember the most recently modified file like this:

```
Set mostRecent = Nothing
...
If mostRecent Is Nothing Then
  Set mostRecent = f
ElseIf f.DateLastModified > mostRecent.DateLastModified Then
  Set mostRecent = f
End If
```