# QTP or UFT VBScript

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Could someone kindly please help us to this concern that we are having

We are using Adobe Acrobat DC 2015 Release

We have a website if a user clicks a link it download a pdf file to the  Downloads folder section in our computer. Now we need a function or some code that we can implement in QTP or UFT that shall be able to read the pdf file from the Downloads folder and look for the word "User" and then print to the screen "Text Found" however we do not want to count the number of times the word "User" is in the pdf only to check if the word "User" is present in the pdf. It would be good if the code can pick up the latest pdf based off the timestamp in the folder so that the most recent pdf is selected. The reason we want to do this is because we don't want to specify in the code exactly the pdf file name because that shall be dynamically generated

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Manetsus. We don't have the code written that's why we are asking for help in terms of how this can be done using VBScript. What we are trying to accomplish is to write a function that we can implement in QTP that shall be able to check a pdf in a specific location to make sure a specific text or phrase is present and then project to the screen that this text or phrase is present. We dont want to implement a loop statement in that function to check if multiple values for that text or phrase is present or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding finding specific text in a PDF file, checkout UFT's [file content checkpoint](http://automated-360.com/unified-functional-testing/i-was-looking-for-pdf-checkpoint/).

Regarding finding the latest PDF file, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807401/3848).

Comment: Hi Motti. Thanks for the links. Would you have some information pertaining to if we want to do the same thing as a file content checkpoint however using VBScript writing a function and then call it and passing a argument. in this situation the path could be a argument. Thanks

Comment: @Tech, If you're using UFT you can use _file content output values_ as well as _file output checkpoints_. Otherwise you'll have to parse the PDF yourself in VBScript (in which case this is not a UFT related question).